# Points System for rewarding participation within sports league

Tags: points, reward

Suppose player's scores determine their rank within a their division within a tournament.  The, points are allocated according to their rank.  The website hosts seasonal scores and tracks players cumulative points.

Thus, I am seeking a rewards system via php/mysql that would allow players to redeem their points for merchandise.

I have seen "points systems" for user interaction via web sites and only assume a similar system could be set up using player's performance points as described above.

I do not have PHP or DB coding abilities but feel this entirely possible. Has anyone seen a similar scenario as I have described?  Just looking for thoughts and comments from those more knowledgeable than I on this subject.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. If the question is: "is this possible", then the answer is certainly "yes". I think you need to just go out and learn some web technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I, as well, felt it was possible.  I have just have not seen any real world examples with similar circumstances.   The "points and rewards" systems observed on the web seem to award points based on user interactions with the site rather than "on field" performance.

Possibly, the better question would be is where does one go to have such a system developed (allowing that I personally do not and will not have these abilities)??